# Find specific text inside a DOM Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like find the next sentence after find "battery" string.
The text doesn't have tags, only quote marks.

```
<html>
<h2 class="inshallah">film</h2>
<h2 class="inshallah">battery</h2> << using this string "battery"
"coucou test tt test" << text to find
<h2 class="inshallah">dress</h2>
</html>
```

I tried this but, it doesn't work if there is no tags after

```js
    var test = $('.inshallah').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().trim() === "battery";
    }).next().text();
    
    console.log(test)
```

Comment: h2 is a tag. You can use $('h2').each(function(){ if ($this).text() == "battery" { doSomething()} });

Comment: @FelixCen I tried .next() to get "coucou test tt test" string, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track. Your code returns `dress` as `.next` only selects the next sibling *element*, what you want to select is the next *textNode*. jQuery has no API for selecting the next `textNode`. You can use the DOM `HTMLElement.nextSibling` property:

```
var text = $('.inshallah').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().trim() === "battery";
}).get(0).nextSibling.textContent;
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. In my case, I had to do: .get(0).next.data;

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("h2").each(function(i, e) {//or .inshallah, it's the same
    if (e.innerText == "battery") {
      alert(e.nextSibling.data);
    }
  })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<h2 class="inshallah">film</h2>
<h2 class="inshallah">battery</h2>
"coucou test tt test"
<h2 class="inshallah">dress</h2>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify html dom element p

Solution 1

```
<html>
<h2 class="inshallah">film</h2>
<h2 class="inshallah">battery</h2>
<p>coucou test tt test</p>
<h2 class="inshallah">dres</h2>
</html>

var test = $('.inshallah').filter(function() {
   return $(this).text().trim() === "battery";
}).next().text();

console.log(test)
```

Solution 2

```
<html>
<h2 class="inshallah">film</h2>
<h2 class="inshallah battery">battery</h2>
<p>coucou test tt test</p>
<h2 class="inshallah">dress</h2>
</html>

$( ".battery" ).next().css( "background-color", "red" );
```

I hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("html").html().split("battery")[1].split("h2>")[1].split("<h2")[0]
```

This is not recommended though.
You should give proper attributes, like classes, id or data-attributes.
Never leave data stranded.
It is advised to encase data in some tag (preferably div).